# Replace right control with right click

Tags: windows, autohotkey

In my laptop, right click button is missing. Also, I don't use right Control and right Alt. So, I want to replace right Control with a right click using AutoHotKey. Is it possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following simple code, you can do this:

```
RAlt::Click ; Simulate left mouse button
RCtrl::Click Right ; Simulate right mouse button
```

Success

Comment: Wow that was a fast acceptance!, I was re-reading your question and saw that you wanted the RCtrl instead of the RAlt, so I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, that was fast. I was just checking for an answer that time when you post the answer. When you post the old code with Alt, I myself replaced it with Ctrl

Comment: Adding [AutoHotKey URL](https://www.autohotkey.com/) for reference and suggesting to use `Appskey::Click Right` as it is a [**menu**] key in the first place

Comment: As I don't use the normal AppsKey myself, I did reprogram this key as a hotkey indeed. And thank you for adding the link to AutoHotKey.